# Which symbols shoud be used to specify versions of a variable in latex?

Tags: algorithm, variables, latex, version

I want to learn **which symbols** we should use in order to show **an updated version of a variable** in latex? Actually, the **'** and **''** appeared good to specify the versions, for example:

a'  ← a and x  
b'  ← a' || c  
b'' ← b' || d

But I need **more** since my algorithm is very long and I want to show each step in detail. I think **~** and **overline** look bad inside algorithm, especially, when **i** is used as variable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use superscripts:

a<sup>(1)</sup> ← a and x
b<sup>(1)</sup> ← a<sup>(1)</sup> || c
b<sup>(2)</sup> ← b<sup>(1)</sup> || d
b<sup>(3)</sup> ← b<sup>(2)</sup> || e
...

Comment: Thanks, it is logical @pkpnd